# How can I run the voting code on Ethereum and get the result?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I executed the code posted [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#voting) on the MIST Ethereum Wallet, the problem is I can't find how to "stop" the voting and get the final result.
 Can you enlighten me please?

Answer (score 0):

In mist go to your contract and run the `winningProposal()` function. This computes the winning proposal taking all previous votes into account.

```
/// @dev Computes the winning proposal taking all
/// previous votes into account.
function winningProposal() constant
        returns (uint winningProposal)
{
    uint winningVoteCount = 0;
    for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
        if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
            winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
            winningProposal = p;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that mist renames / sanitizes the function names, it could be named `Winning Proposal` or `winning proposal`. You can call it without any arguments.

It will return the ID of the proposal with the most votes. See `proposals` struct:

```
// This is a type for a single proposal.
struct Proposal
{
    bytes32 name;   // short name (up to 32 bytes)
    uint voteCount; // number of accumulated votes
}
```